# How can I tell if a protein has been denatured?

Tags: proteins

So i recently done an experiment using egg albumin, and we had 5 test tubes. the goal was to see if they have been denatured. 
1- heat 
2-acid (HNO3)
3-base (NaOH)
4- Alchol (ethanol)
5- heavy metal ions (AgNO3)

So some of the test tubes became cloudy/milky and some clear. Is it the clear ones that has been denatured? I don't know how to tell.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your starting state? If it was clear before you added the factor of change and the protein was in its normal conformation, then what does that say if solution stays clear or becomes cloudy?

Comment: untreated egg albumen is, contradictory to the colloquial term 'egg white', a clear mass. That is its native state.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when protein denatures, it typically aggregates and precipitates from solution. I would expect a denatured protein to create a cloudy solution, or actual precipitates in the form of little globs or fine wisps. A solution where protein is correctly formed and solubilized in the solution should be clear.